# grid_remove not removing widgets

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to python, and it's entirely possible that there is some small mistake on my part that's causing it, but I've been trying to remove a ttk frame widget that was placed using grid(). I've been trying grid_forget, but it's not working. Here are some parts of the code:

```
def wait():
    mainframe.grid_remove()
    root.after(1000)
    mainframe.grid()

root = Tk()
mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
mainframe['borderwidth'] = 5
mainframe['relief'] = 'sunken'
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
#...
root.option_add('*tearOff', FALSE)
menubar = Menu(root)
root['menu'] = menubar
filemenu = Menu(menubar)
filemenu.add_command(label='Test', command=wait)
```

Pressing the button in the file menu hasn't been working, though. What am I doing wrong? Also, when I do it right, will it hide everything that the frame contains?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's examine these three lines of code:

```
mainframe.grid_remove()
root.after(1000)
mainframe.grid()
```

The first line does indeed successfully remove the grid. However, until the event loop has a chance to update the display, it remains visible.

The second line *freezes the gui*, including removing the ability to update the display.

The third line adds the frame back. Since the GUI didn't have a chance to update the display between `grid_remove()` and `grid()`, there is no visible change.

If you want the frame to be hidden for one second, change the code to this:

```
mainframe.grid_remove()
root.after(1000, mainframe.grid)
```

The above will not freeze your GUI, and will cause `mainframe.grid` to be called one second in the future.

To answer the last part of your question: if you hide the frame, everything inside the frame will also be hidden.